# How to check if input is a key in dictionary even partially?

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say you have a dictionary that has a grocery item (key) and its price(value). We ask the user for input (grocery item) and they type in whatever. They dont know what item is in the dictionary or not. Im trying to specify that even if the input contains 1 word of the item in the dictionary, to use that as the key and get the price.
So if the official key in the dictionary was "Milk Gallon", and the user types in "milk", how can i make them reference the same thing? If they type milk i want the output to be the value of "Milk gallon"?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if` `in`
you can try this:-

```
store = {"milk gallon":100,"tomato":50,"fish":190}
user = input("Whatever you want-->")
for i in store:
    if user.lower() in i:
        user = i

print(user)
```